# PySpark dataframe convert unusual string format to Timestamp

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, timestamp

I am using PySpark through Spark 1.5.0.
I have an unusual String format in rows of a column for datetime values. It looks like this:

```
Row[(datetime='2016_08_21 11_31_08')]
```

Is there a way to convert this unorthodox `yyyy_mm_dd hh_mm_dd` format into a Timestamp?
Something that can eventually come along the lines of

```
df = df.withColumn("date_time",df.datetime.astype('Timestamp'))
```

I had thought that Spark SQL functions like `regexp_replace` could work, but of course I need to replace
`_` with `-` in the date half
and `_` with `:` in the time part.

I was thinking I could split the column in 2 using `substring` and count backward from the end of time. Then do the 'regexp_replace' separately, then concatenate. But this seems to many operations? Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

**Spark >= 2.2**

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_timestamp

(sc
    .parallelize([Row(dt='2016_08_21 11_31_08')])
    .toDF()
    .withColumn("parsed", to_timestamp("dt", "yyyy_MM_dd HH_mm_ss"))
    .show(1, False))

## +-------------------+-------------------+
## |dt                 |parsed             |
## +-------------------+-------------------+
## |2016_08_21 11_31_08|2016-08-21 11:31:08|
## +-------------------+-------------------+
```

**Spark < 2.2**

It is nothing that `unix_timestamp` cannot handle:

```py
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.functions import unix_timestamp

(sc
    .parallelize([Row(dt='2016_08_21 11_31_08')])
    .toDF()
    .withColumn("parsed", unix_timestamp("dt", "yyyy_MM_dd HH_mm_ss")
    # For Spark <= 1.5
    # See issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11724 
    .cast("double")
    .cast("timestamp"))
    .show(1, False))

## +-------------------+---------------------+
## |dt                 |parsed               |
## +-------------------+---------------------+
## |2016_08_21 11_31_08|2016-08-21 11:31:08.0|
## +-------------------+---------------------+
```

In both cases the format string should be compatible with Java [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: Great. You can check https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11724 for some details.

Comment: can I use the `unix_timestamp` function if the timestamp string has timezones?  That is, the pattern is `yyyy_MM_dd HH_mm_ss z` like `1995_05_20 20_30_11 -400`?

Answer (score 19):

zero323's answer answers the question, but I wanted to add that if your datetime string has a standard format, you should be able to cast it directly into timestamp type:

```
df.withColumn('datetime', col('datetime_str').cast('timestamp'))
```

It has the advantage of handling **milliseconds**, while *unix_timestamp* only has only second-precision (*to_timestamp* works with milliseconds too but requires Spark >= 2.2 as zero323 stated). I tested it on Spark 2.3.0, using the following format: '2016-07-13 14:33:53.979' (with milliseconds, but it also works without them).

Answer (score 2):

I add some more code lines from [Florent F's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52369875/5595995) for better understanding and running the snippet in local machine:

```
import os, pdb, sys
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, ArrayType  
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

sc = pyspark.SparkContext('local[*]')
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

# preparing some example data - df1 with String type and df2 with Timestamp type
df1 = sc.parallelize([{"key":"a", "date":"2016-02-01"}, 
    {"key":"b", "date":"2016-02-02"}]).toDF()
df1.show()

df2 = df1.withColumn('datetime', col('date').cast("timestamp"))
df2.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just want to add more resources and example into this discussion.
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html
For example, if your ts string is "22 Dec 2022 19:06:36 EST", then the format is "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"

Answer (score 0):

**spark - 2.4**

`to_timestamp()` is not able to handle datetime string with daylight saving, whereas `unix_timestamp()` saves it. I was using with `from_utc_timestamp()` for zone conversion.

Directly using datetime string gave 1 hour incorrect result with `from_utc_timestamp()`. By using `from_utc_timestamp(unix_timestamp().cast(TimestampType()))` gave the right conversion.