# Pyspark sql add letter in datetype value

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, sqldatetime

I have epoch time values in Spark dataframe like `1569872588019` and I'm using pyspark sql in jupyter notebook.

I'm using the `from_unixtime` method to convert it to date.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT from_unixtime(dataepochvalues/1000,'yyyy-MM-dd%%HH:MM:ss') AS date FROM testdata
```

The result is like: `2019-04-30%%11:09:11`

But what I want is like: `2019-04-30T11:04:48.366Z`

I tried to add T and Z instead of %% in date but failed.

How can I insert `T` and `Z` letter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify those letters using single quotes. For your desired output, use the following date and time pattern:

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
```

Using your example:

```
spark.sql(
    """SELECT from_unixtime(1569872588019/1000,"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:MM:ss'Z'") AS date"""
).show()
#+--------------------+
#|                date|
#+--------------------+
#|2019-09-30T14:09:08Z|
#+--------------------+
```

Comment: ahh I see , I also tried with backslash and backquote but I put ' at beginning instead of your " so failed. Thanks for your effort and answer.

Comment: I got another little question. when I want to get minute in this result "2019-09-30T14:09:08Z" , Is there anyway instead of substring do you know ?

Comment: You can [convert the string to a `TimestampType`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39088473/5858851) and then use `pyspark.sql.functions.minute` to extract the minute.